# Unable to async load vue component in nested folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I am using webpack 1.13 and Vue 2.1

Say the folder structure is

```
src__
     |
     page.vue
     views___
             |
             mainViews____
                          |
                          mainContainer.vue
```

where in page.vue I have

```
<template>
    <component v-bind:is='"mainContainer"'></component>
</template>
.
.
.
beforeMount () {
    Vue.component('mainContainer', function (resolve) {
        require(['./views/mainViews/mainContainer'], resolve)
    })
}
```

The component is not loaded.

but when the component being loaded is a sibling of the component its loaded from, it works.

```
src__
     |
     page.vue
     mainContainer.vue


Vue.component('mainContainer', function (resolve) {
    require(['./mainContainer'], resolve)
})
```

There are no erros in the console or the build. I guess my question is why does it only work when the component is a sibling in the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the component and register it in the page.vue, like this:

`<script>
import MainContainer from "maincontainer's file path"`

`export default {
...
   components: {
      mainContainer: MainContainer
   }
}
</script>`

Comment: but that causes the component to be loaded initially, where as the vue.component require() syntax allows for lazy loading, by webpack splitting the build into chunks and calling the component over ajax only once its needed, reducing the size of whats initially loaded on the page. 
so what you are saying does work to load a component, but it doesnt explain what im running into

Comment: ahh, I see what you mean. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: no worries ^-^ at least I have a workaround for now